# itk filereader causes access violation exception

Tags: c++, exception, vtk, itk

I have a problem with an Access Violation Exception.
I am using itk and read a File with it's file reader.

```
ThreeDImageFloatType* MyClass::loadImage(std::string filename){
const char* cfilename = filename.c_str();
fileReader = ImageFileReaderType::New();
fileReader->SetFileName(cfilename);

try{ 
    fileReader->Update();
}catch( ... ) {
    std::cerr << "failed to read file " << filename << std::endl; 
}

CastFilterType::Pointer castFilter = CastFilterType::New();
castFilter->SetInput(fileReader->GetOutput());


castFilter->Update();

//ThreeDImageFloatType *t3dim = castFilter->GetOutput();
t3dim = castFilter->GetOutput();
return t3dim;
}
```

This is a function the class also contains 2 global variables:

```
ImageFileReaderType::Pointer fileReader;
ThreeDImageFloatType *t3dim;
```

Now if you call the the function in the class from for example my main method and try to access the return value, something like  `t3dim->GetLargestPossibleRegion().GetSize();`. I get an access violation error. It is important to notice if i don't outsource the code, and have it within the main method, it works like a charm. What could be the problem? How do i fix that?

[edit]
I tried replacing the string filename with a const char* filename. The main method looks like this.

```
MyClass imIO;

const char* filename = "path to file";
ThreeDImageFloatType *t3dim = imIO.loadImage(filename);
t3dim->GetLargestPossibleRegion().GetSize();
```

Again if i put the code from the function completly in the main method it works.

[/edit]

[offtopic]
maybe a moderator can tag it as itk, since it is an itk specific question?
[/offtopic]

Comment: ITK - http://itk.org - ITK is an open-source, cross-platform system that provides developers with an extensive suite of software tools for image analysis.

Comment: I know that, i am using it. ???.

Comment: Of course you know what ITK is, but other people will not know what it is.  I did not know.  I put the link there so that other people could more easily find out what it is, and read its documentation if they liked.

Comment: Didn't think about that, your right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer myself. The Solution to the Problem lies within this line:

```
fileReader = ImageFileReaderType::New();
```

It's a smart pointer. So when the function returns, it gets unregistered. So the pointer received from that function to an internal buffer (the read file), can't be used any more. While the pointer points to actual memory, it can't be accessed any more. Access Violation Error.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see here is that you are passing `filename` by copy to the function. The pointer received from the call to `c_str()` is not valid once the function returns.

Is `ImageFileReaderType` keeping a reference to this pointer and using it in the call to `GetSize()`?

If so, then you might want to try out some other stategy to keep the `filename` variable alive throughout `t3dim`'s lifetime.

**Follow-up to your update**: this may sound like another silly attempt, but do you check for null pointers? Are you *sure* that all the `GetOutput()`methods return valid objects? A lot of C++ libraries (unfortunately) prefer returning null pointers to throwing exceptions...

Since you said that if you put everything in `main()` it works, I assume there is some subtlety going on in your transformation to obtain the current code. Can we see both samples to compare?

Comment: @inf.ig.sh: can you post some client code? I don't think there is enough in the posted listing to diagnose your error.

Comment: I am pretty sure thats not the issue in the main method it looks right now like this: 

MyClass imIO;

const char* filename = "path to file";

ThreeDImageFloatType *t3dim = imIO.loadImage(filename)

after that i try to access the t3dim pointer as described above. Again if i put the code completly in the main method it works.

Comment: I see that code isn't really readable in comments so i will update the question.

Comment: Right.  c_str() does not return a copy of the characters in the std::string. If the std::string goes out of scope, then the c_str() you got out of it may become invalid.  This may not be the problem, but it's something to pay attention to.

Comment: I of course debugged it before asking the question. No it's not a null pointer.

Comment: sry found the answaer by myself